# PowerPivot - How to grab data from Yahoo webservices

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerview

I would like to import weather forecasts in PowerPivot for a specified country by using Yahoo API.
So first of all I got the data stream URL including all requiered parameters to get forecasts (it works in my browser).

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D612977&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=
```

Then I tried to use it as "Other data Stream" in PowerPivot to grab the content.
However I got the following strange error about DTD :

> Cannot connect to the specified feed. Verify the connection and try
>   again. Reason: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML
>   document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on
>   XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create
>   method

Any idea to solve that ?

Comment: Did this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13854068/2258

Comment: The trick is about parsing a XML file by using C#, that is completly different from parsing data by using PowerPivot.

Comment: Have you tried using [Power Query](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379)?  I was able to take your url, choose From Web in Power Query, and get data back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest was to install PowerQuery for Microsoft Excel then creating a new request to Yahoo Web Services. 
After parsing data in PowerQuery (split columns, etc) , formatted data is available in a PowerPivot tab and you can use it as well as direct imported data in PowerPivot.