# DTD prohibited Exception with ManifestReader (c#)

Tags: c#, xml, manifest

My application gets a manifest xml and i want to read it via the ManifestReader, but on some machines i get the error "For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method", the problem is ManifestReader doesn't take this parameter and enabling it via OS isn't an option. (I read already the similar topic @ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854068/dtd-prohibited-in-xml-document-exception))

So basically i need one of the two following solutions (or a third if it's better ^^)

- Passing this parameter or it's equivalent to ManifestReader to enable it to read the manifest, or
- Read the manifest xml via XmlReader and converting it into ApplicationManifest object

Comment: Does your XML actually contain a `DOCTYPE`?  Should it?

Comment: @CharlesMager it doesn't contain a DOCTYPE, and unfortunately i don't quite know if it should, it's an application manifest created by visual studio.

Comment: I don't think it should, but I'm not very familiar with it.  If it did have one you could have removed it before loading, but that won't help if you don't.