# Implementing the xmlreadersettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on

I am using my organization's federation services for implementing an SSO following the guidelines of [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/).

But I am getting the following error:

```
For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
```

I found the code to bypass this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854068/dtd-prohibited-in-xml-document-exception). But it doesn't say where I have to write this code. Do bear with me if this seems too trivial.

Comment: You'll have to show us the code where you are attempting to read the xml for us to have any clue where you would need to put the solution implementation.

Comment: @Kevin I haven't written any XML code explicitly. Maybe owin has it somewhere?