# Window.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument does not support <!Doctype or <!CDATA

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, xmldocument

I am trying to load a XML file using the Window.Data.Xml.Dom namespace included in the Universal Platform for Windows 10. I have to do that because then I need to transform this XML using XSTLTranslator

I am using the following code to realize that :

```
var xslfile = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(xslFilePath)
               .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var xslDocument = XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xslfile).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var xsltPocessor = new Windows.Data.Xml.Xsl.XsltProcessor(xslDocument);
var xmlDocumentToTransform = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocumentToTransform.LoadXml(xmlToTransform);
var generatedHtml = xsltPocessor.TransformToString(xmlDocumentToTransform);
```

My issue is that apparently when I try to load the XML into a XML Document with

```
var xmlDocumentToTransform = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocumentToTransform.LoadXml(xmlToTransform);
```

before transforming it I get an error 0xC00CE584. See XML example below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE dmodule[

<!NOTATION cgm PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//NOTATION Computer Graphics Metafile//EN">
<!NOTATION jpeg PUBLIC "+//ISBN 0-7923-9432-1::Graphic Notation//NOTATION 
Joint Photographic Experts Group Raster//EN">
<!NOTATION swf PUBLIC "-//S1000D//NOTATION X-SHOCKWAVE-FLASH 3D Models 
Encoding//EN">
<!NOTATION png PUBLIC "-//W3C//NOTATION Portable Network Graphics//EN">
]>
<dmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:dc="http://www.purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_4-
   1/xml_schema_flat/proced.xsd">
   <rdf:Description>
      <dc:title>Tire - Remove and install a new item</dc:title>
   </rdf:Description>
</dmodule>
```

I think the error comes from the !Doctype node in the header because a soon as I remove this info I don't have any error parsing the xml. Is that an expected behaviour or a bug ? In classic .Net I don't  receive this error.

PS : The XMLs comes from the bike dataset provided as an example of the S1000D Specification examples

Comment: See if adding the following code works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854068/dtd-prohibited-in-xml-document-exception XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your code in try-catch, you should be able to see more describing error:

```
        try
        {
            var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("test.xml");
            var content = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            var xmlDocumentToTransform = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocumentToTransform.LoadXml(content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var dlg = new MessageDialog(ex.ToString());
            await dlg.ShowAsync();
        }
```

In this case the error is:

[image: Error XML]

The solution is (as Barry pointed out in the comment) to set the DtdProcessing-property to Ignore (or to Parse, if the framework supports it) like following:

```
            var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("testi.xml");
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore };
            using (var openRead = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                using (var stream = openRead.AsStreamForRead())
                {
                    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
                    {
                        xmlDoc.Load(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
```