# How to Solve DTD is prohibited in this xml document in WCF while connecting with Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xamarin.forms, dtd

I'm trying to connect my WCF service in Xamarine Forms, but in runtime I am getting this error

> For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

LoginWCFService.svc.cs

```
public class LoginWCFService : ILoginWCFService
    {   
        public string LoginUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            bool res = false;

            if (userInfo.uName!="" && userInfo.pWord != "" || userInfo.uName != null && userInfo.pWord != null)
            {   
                    result = "Login Successfull...";                
            }
            else
            {
                res = false;
                result = "Empty username or password";
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
```

ILoginWCFService.cs

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILoginWCFService
    {
        [OperationContract]        
        string LoginUserDetails(UserDetails UserInfo);
    }

    public class UserDetails
    {
        string UserName = string.Empty;
        string Password = string.Empty;

        [DataMember]
        public string uName
        {
            get { return UserName; }
            set { UserName = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string pWord
        {
            get { return Password; }
            set { Password = value; }
        }
    }
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>     
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>        
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
      <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILoginWCFService" />        
          </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
          <endpoint address="http://wcfapi.local/LoginWCFService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILoginWCFService"
              contract="WcfService_Omss.ILoginWCFService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILoginWCFService" />
      </client>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Consuming WCF in Xamarine Form

LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
WCFServiceReference.LoginWCFServiceClient client = new LoginWCFServiceClient();
                    client.Open();
                    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
                    user.uName = Uname.Text.ToString();
                    user.pWord = Pass.Text.ToString();

                    var res =  client.LoginUserDetails(user);  //Getting error here

                    if (res == "Login Successfull...")
                        await DisplayAlert("Message", "Login Successfull...", "Cancel");
                    else
                        await DisplayAlert("Message", "Login failed...", "Cancel");

                    client.Close();
```

Can anyone please tell me where I have to do changes to resolve this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854068/dtd-prohibited-in-xml-document-exception

Answer (score 1):

This error has nothing to do with the wcf service. 
As the message says, set the DtdProcessing property on `XmlReaderSettings` to `Parse` and pass the settings to the `XmlReader.Create` method. 
You can refer to the code below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.dtdprocessing?view=net-6.0

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.IO;

public class Sample {

  public static void Main() {

    // Set the validation settings.
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler (ValidationCallBack);

    // Create the XmlReader object.
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("itemDTD.xml", settings);

    // Parse the file.
    while (reader.Read());
  }

  // Display any validation errors.
  private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Validation Error: {0}", e.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lan Huang for your answer, But I already implemented this still getting error. Can you please tell me where exactly I have to put this code?

Comment: I checked posts with similar problems, this error may be caused by other problems, you can check.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22e3555a-3f37-4599-8310-bf8edc383fe2/error-for-security-reasons-dtd-is-prohibited-in-this-xml-document?forum=xamarinforms and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231007/change-xmlreadersettings-for-autogenerated-wcf-client

Comment: Ok sure. Thanks Lan Huang