# "DTD is prohibited" exception when transforming XML file

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, xslt

I've created a custom `HTMLHelper` which is supposed to render parsed XML. The method takes the XML and the path to an `XSL` file and should return HTML.

When I access the page, I get the error

> XmlException: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

As you can see in my code below, I'm setting `DtdProcessing` to`Parse` in the `XmlReaderSettings` (as the exception suggests), which I thought would resolve the issue. On closer inspection, the exception is occurring at the line:

```
transformObj.Load(xsltPath);
```

But I can't see how I can pass `XmlReaderSettings` to that method so as to set the `DtdProcessing` property. The only overloads of `XslCompiledTransform.Load` which accept a settings object expect a `XsltSettings` object, which doesn't have a `DtdProcessing` property.

The full method is as follows:

```
public static IHtmlContent RenderXml(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string xml, string xsltPath)
{
    XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
    // Create XslCompiledTransform object to load and compile XSLT file.  
    XslCompiledTransform transformObj = new XslCompiledTransform();
    transformObj.Load(xsltPath);

    // Create XMLReaderSetting object to assign DtdProcessing, Validation type  
    XmlReaderSettings xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    xmlSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    xmlSettings.MaxCharactersFromEntities = 1024; // Prevent DoS attacks
    xmlSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;

    // Create XMLReader object to Transform xml value with XSLT setting
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), xmlSettings);

    using (reader)
    {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformObj.Transform(reader, args, writer);

        // Generate HTML string from StringWriter  
        HtmlString htmlString = new HtmlString(writer.ToString());
        return htmlString;
    }
}
```

And in my view I'm using:

```
@Html.RenderXml(ViewBag.XML as string, ViewBag.XSL as string);
```

I've reviewed the advice in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854068/dtd-prohibited-in-xml-document-exception) but as far as I can tell I've already taken the steps suggested. The accepted answer to [this MSDN question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5b1e21e-3226-4c42-b6ad-5fd06e5ca555/xslcompiledtransform-cannot-process-xml-containing-dtd?forum=xmlandnetfx) seems to hint at an answer but I haven't been able to work out how to make use of it.

Comment: Try Ignore instead of Parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the XSLT uses or references a DTD, pass an XmlReader with the necessary XmlReaderSettings to the Load method, i.e. use the overload https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.load?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Xsl_XslCompiledTransform_Load_System_Xml_XmlReader_ with

```
using (XmlReader xsltReader = XmlReader.Create(xsltPath, new XmlReaderSettings() { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse }))
{
  transformObj.Load(xsltReader);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, that's what I was missing - that there was an overload that accepted a `XmlReader` parameter. Fourteen years on from that MSDN answer and you're still helping people out with XSL transformations!