# How can I say a file is SVG without using a magic number?

Tags: python, xml, svg, file-format, magic-numbers

An `SVG` file is basically an `XML` file so I could use the string `<?xml` (or the hex representation: `'3c 3f 78 6d 6c'`) as a magic number but there are a few opposing reason not to do that if for example there are extra white-spaces it could break this check.

The other images I need/expect to check are all binaries and have magic numbers. How can I fast check if the file is an `SVG` format without using the extension eventually using Python?

Comment: how about reading the beginning of the file as binary - if you can't find any magic numbers, you read it as text and try to match it to your known textual patterns?

Comment: @DJV Sounds reasonable. And I don't see how it couldn't break.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

XML is not required to start with the `<?xml` preamble, so testing for that prefix is not a good detection technique — not to mention that it would identify every XML as SVG. A decent detection, and really easy to implement, is to use a real XML parser to test that the file is well-formed XML that contains the `svg` top-level element:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et

def is_svg(filename):
    tag = None
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        try:
            for event, el in et.iterparse(f, ('start',)):
                tag = el.tag
                break
        except et.ParseError:
            pass
    return tag == '{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}svg'
```

Using `cElementTree` ensures that the detection is efficient through the use of [expat](https://libexpat.github.io/); `timeit` shows that an SVG file was detected as such in ~200μs, and a non-SVG in 35μs. The `iterparse` API enables the parser to forego creating the whole element tree (module name notwithstanding) and only read the initial portion of the document, regardless of total file size.

Comment: By reading the question, the mixing of binary magic numbers and XML triggered a red alert. This answer makes clear that parsing a binary format requires one approach, and reading a (text-based) XML requires a COMPLETELY DIFFERENT approach.

Comment: @heltonbiker Exactly. Magic numbers do have one thing going for them: raw performance. This is why the answer includes a code sample that demonstrates an *efficient* implementation of the proposed approach.

Comment: Also, if I understant right, a binary file is inherently unstructured, such as a plain-text file. In a plain-text, then, we should include shebangs, doctypes, and so on, while binary need those terse, cryptic magic numbers. I believe, in that sense, that this magic-number stuff is reminiscent of smallest-size-possible, low-level, "old way" of storing data to files, while XML and JSON to name a few are more modern, human-readable, inflated and redundant way of storing data to files. Both approaches differ in more than one aspect, then.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html): "Changed in version 3.3: This module will use a fast implementation whenever available. The `xml.etree.cElementTree` module is deprecated."

Comment: I like this, but beware: The [XML vulnerabilities page](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.html#xml-vulnerabilities) mentions a vulnerability to [billion laughs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3451203) and similar attacks. Testing verified that `et.iterparse()` does indeed blow up. The docs recommend [defusedxml](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.html#the-defusedxml-package).

Comment: For those wondering about the syntax of the expected `tag` value: an xml tag with svg [namespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course#declaring_namespaces) looks like `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`, and the `xml` module expands this to `{<namespace uri>}<tag name>` as described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces), so that becomes `'{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}svg'`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try reading the beginning of the file as binary - if you can't find any magic numbers, you read it as a text file and match to any textual patterns you wish. Or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

This is from `man file` ([here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/file.1.html)), for the unix `file` command:

> The magic tests are used to check for files with data in particular fixed formats. The canonical example of this is a binary executable ... These files have a “magic number” stored in a particular place near the beginning of the file that tells the UNIX operating system that the file is a binary executable, and which of several types thereof. **The concept of a “magic” has been applied by extension to data files.  Any file with some invariant identifier at a small fixed offset into the file can usually be described in this way.** ...

(my emphasis)

And here's one example of the "magic" that the `file` command uses to identify an `svg` file (see [source](https://github.com/file/file/blob/f58043c39891ff165660b84bc342820106ded5b2/magic/Magdir/sgml) for more):

```
...
0       string        \<?xml\ version=
>14     regex         ['"\ \t]*[0-9.]+['"\ \t]*
>>19    search/4096   \<svg         SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
...
0       string        \<svg         SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
...
```

As described by [`man magic`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/magic.5.html), each line follows the format `<offset> <type> <test> <message>`.

If I understand correctly, the code above looks for the literal `"<?xml version="`. If that is found, it looks for a version number, as described by the regular expression. If that is found, it searches the next 4096 bytes until it finds the literal `"<svg"`. If any of this fails, it looks for the literal `"<svg"` at the start of the file, and so on.

Something similar could be implemented in Python.

Note there's also [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic), which provides an interface to `libmagic`, as used by the unix `file` command.

Comment: An xml file might start with a BOM (byte order mark). As this code seems to read `<?xml` from byte zero I think it would fail if the xml file includes a BOM. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @mortb The code above represents just one of many patterns from the [source](https://github.com/file/file/blob/f58043c39891ff165660b84bc342820106ded5b2/magic/Magdir/sgml) of the `file` command for Linux.

Comment: I understand. I think it is great that you used a ready made solution. I just made the remark in case someone gets an edge case error due to having a BOM at the beginning of the svg file.