# Allow SVG files to be uploaded to ImageField via Django admin

Tags: python, django, svg, django-forms

I'm switching to SVG images to represent categories on my e-commerce platform. I was using `models.ImageField` in the Category model to store the images before, but the `forms.ImageField` validation is not capable of handling a vector-based image (and therefore rejects it).

I don't require thorough validation against harmful files, since all uploads will be done via the Django Admin. It looks like I'll have to switch to a `models.FileField` in my model, but I do want warnings against uploading invalid images.

Nick Khlestov wrote a [SVGAndImageFormField](https://7webpages.com/blog/how-to-have-svg-allowed-as-an-image-for-django-rest-framework/) (find source within the article, I don't have enough reputation to post more links) over [django-rest-framework's ImageField](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L1392). How do I use this solution over Django's ImageField (and not the DRF one)?

Comment: The basic difference between an ImageField and a FileField is that the first checks if a file is an image using Pillow and offers a couple of attributes possibly irrelevant to you (height, width). Isn't a FileField adequate for your requirements? https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py

Comment: @Wtower I would prefer if it doesn't let non-image formats through.

Comment: Even though the OP does not worry about harmful files, it may be good to keep in mind how easy it is to make a harmful `svg`. For example, [billion laughs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451203/) **will** crash your server if you use `xml.etree` (as suggested in many of the answers here).

Answer (score 17):

I have never used `SVGAndImageFormField` so I cannot really comment on that. Personally I would have opted for a simple application of `FileField`, but that clearly depends on the project requirements. I will expand on that below:

As mentioned in the comment, the basic difference between an ImageField and a FileField is that the first checks if a file is an image using Pillow:

> Inherits all attributes and methods from FileField, but also validates that the uploaded object is a valid image.

Reference: [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#imagefield), [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py)

It also offers a couple of attributes possibly irrelevant to the SVG case (height, width).

Therefore, the model field could be:

```
    svg = models.FileField(upload_to=..., validators=[validate_svg])
```

You can use a function like `is_svg` as provided in the relevant question:

[How can I say a file is SVG without using a magic number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136264/how-can-i-say-a-file-is-svg-without-using-a-magic-number)

Then a function to validate SVG:

```
def validate_svg(file, valid):
    if not is_svg(file):
        raise ValidationError("File not svg")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is pretty much what `SVGAndImageFormField` does.

Comment: What is that second `valid` parameter? Was it used in older Django versions? (it's blowing up on 1.11)

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that [`SVGAndImageFormField`](https://gist.github.com/ambivalentno/9bc42b9a417677d96a21) has no dependencies on DRF's `ImageField`, it only adds to the validation done by `django.forms.ImageField`.

So to accept SVGs in the Django Admin I <s>changed the model's `ImageField` to a `FileField` and</s> specified an override as follows:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = []
        field_classes = {
            'image_field': SVGAndImageFormField,
        }

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

It now accepts all previous image formats along with SVG.

EDIT: Just found out that this works even if you don't switch from `models.ImageField` to `models.FileField`. The `height` and `width` attributes of `models.ImageField` will still work for raster image types, and will be set to `None` for SVG.

Comment: May be helpful for someone. field_classes in meta of the form available only from django 1.9, for those who uses older version, you need to explicitly define field in form.

Comment: Not working anymore, same reason as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006200/allow-svg-files-to-be-uploaded-to-imagefield-via-django-admin#comment86755700_46846452

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that works as a simple model field, that you can put instead of `models.ImageField`:

```
class Icon(models.Model):
    image_file = SVGAndImageField()
```

You need to define following classes and functions somewhere in your code:

```
from django.db import models

class SVGAndImageField(models.ImageField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': SVGAndImageFieldForm}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().formfield(**defaults)
```

And here is how `SVGAndImageFieldForm` looks like:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class SVGAndImageFieldForm(forms.ImageField):
    def to_python(self, data):
        try:
            f = super().to_python(data)
        except ValidationError:
            return validate_svg(data)

        return f
```

Function `validate_svg` I took from other solutions:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et

def validate_svg(f):
    # Find "start" word in file and get "tag" from there
    f.seek(0)
    tag = None
    try:
        for event, el in et.iterparse(f, ('start',)):
            tag = el.tag
            break
    except et.ParseError:
        pass

    # Check that this "tag" is correct
    if tag != '{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}svg':
        raise ValidationError('Uploaded file is not an image or SVG file.')

    # Do not forget to "reset" file
    f.seek(0)

    return f
```

---

Also if you want to use **SVG files only** model field - you can do it more simple.

Just create class, inherited from `models.FileField`, and in `__init__` method you can add `validate_svg` function to `kwargs['validators']`.

Or just add this validator to `models.FileField` and be happy :)

Comment: Not working anymore with Django 2.0. Even if the svg validation passes and to_python returns the file, the form will still raise an error with

"File extension 'svg' is not allowed. Allowed extensions are: 'blp, bmp, bufr, cur, pcx, dcx, dds, ps, eps, fit, fits, fli, flc, ftc, ftu, gbr, gif, grib, h5, hdf, png, jp2, j2k, jpc, jpf, jpx, j2c, icns, ico, im, iim, tif, tiff, jfif, jpe, jpg, jpeg, mpg, mpeg, mpo, msp, palm, pcd, pdf, pxr, pbm, pgm, ppm, psd, bw, rgb, rgba, sgi, ras, tga, webp, wmf, emf, xbm, xpm'."

Comment: I had to override SVGAndImageFieldForm.run_validators in the same fashion as SVGAndImageFieldForm.run_python in order to get this to work

Comment: @Fandekasp, can you clarify if you were able to get it to work on Django 2.0? Where is `SVGAndImageFieldForm.run_validators`?

Comment: `class SVGAndImageFieldForm(forms.ImageField): default_validators = [FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=get_available_image_extensions() + ["svg"])]`

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, validation for `SVGAndImageFormField` will fail because extensions are checked using `django.core.validators.validate_image_file_extension`, which is the default validator for an `ImageField`.

A workaround for this would be creating a custom validator adding `"svg"` to the accepted extensions.

**Edited**: Thanks @Ilya Semenov for your comment

```
from django.core.validators import (
    get_available_image_extensions,
    FileExtensionValidator,
)


def validate_image_and_svg_file_extension(value):
    allowed_extensions = get_available_image_extensions() + ["svg"]
    return FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=allowed_extensions)(value)
```

Then, override the `default_validators` attribute in the `SvgAndImageFormField`:

```
class SVGAndImageFormField(DjangoImageField):
    default_validators = [validate_image_and_svg_file_extension]
# ...
```

Comment: This code is not correct, as it modifies the return value of `get_available_image_extensions()` in-place by reference. Depending on the underlying implementation, this may break things. You should be doing `get_available_image_extensions() + ["svg"]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that works for me with Django4.2:

Also I make use of [defusedxml](https://pypi.org/project/defusedxml/) here as suggested per [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html#module-xml):

> Warning
>
> The XML modules are not secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. If you need to parse untrusted or unauthenticated data see the XML vulnerabilities and The defusedxml Package sections.

```
# form_fields.py

import defusedxml.cElementTree as et
from django.core import validators
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms import ImageField


def validate_image_file_extension(value):
    return validators.FileExtensionValidator(
        allowed_extensions=validators.get_available_image_extensions()+['svg']
    )(value)

class ImageAndSvgField(ImageField):
    default_validators = [validate_image_file_extension]

    def to_python(self, data):
        try:
            f = super().to_python(data)
        except ValidationError as e:
            if e.code != 'invalid_image':
                raise

            # Give it a chance - maybe its SVG!
            f = data
            if not self.is_svg(f):
                # Nope it is not.
                raise

            f.content_type = 'image/svg+xml'
            if hasattr(f, "seek") and callable(f.seek):
                f.seek(0)
        return f

        
    def is_svg(self, f):
        if hasattr(f, "seek") and callable(f.seek):
            f.seek(0)        

        try:
            doc = et.parse(f)
            root = doc.getroot()
            return root.tag == '{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}svg'
        except et.ParseError:
            return False

# model_fields.py

from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageField

from . import form_fields


class ImageAndSvgField(ImageField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return super().formfield(
            **{
                "form_class": form_fields.ImageAndSvgField,
                **kwargs,
            }
        )

# modesl.py

from django.db import models

from .model_fields import ImageAndSvgField


class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    image = ImageAndSvgField(upload_to='mymodel_images/', blank=True)
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, FileField

class TemplatesModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Templates
        exclude = []
        field_classes = {
            'image': FileField,
        }

@admin.register(Templates)
class TemplatesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TemplatesModelForm
```

its work

Comment: The field on the model is still an `ImageField`, so the validation still happens on the model.