# How to store SVG files in Django model?

Tags: django, svg

I've got a simple Django template that allows a user to input an image from the system. It should accept only JPEG, JPG, PNG and SVG files. The first three seems to work well. However, SVG doesnt get uploaded. Instead, it sends an error message stating: ***'Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image'***

How do I store a SVG file into my database model?

You can view my current code below:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import os
from PIL import Image
from datetime import date
import datetime

def get_directory_path(instance, filename):
    file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    today = date.today()
    t = datetime.datetime.now() 
    day, month, year = today.day, today.month, today.year
    hour, minutes, seconds = t.hour, t.minute, t.second
    if file_extension[1] in ['.jpg','.png','.jpeg','.svg']:
        filename = str(day) + str(month) + str(year) + str(hour) + str(minutes) + str(seconds) + '.png'
        dir = 'media'
    else:
        dir = 'others'
    path = '{0}/{1}'.format(dir, filename)
    return path

# Create your models here.
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_directory_path, default = 'media/sample.png')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms

from myapp.models import Image

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""Image upload form"""
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        exclude = ('created_date',)
```

insert_image.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Insert an image </title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1> Please upload an image below </h1>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>

    <p> Required format: PNG, JPEG, JPG, SVG </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't use a Filefield instead?

Comment: Is it the same thing as ImageField()?

Comment: ImageField accepts images only whereas FileField accepts every format. And if you don't want FileField then this answer will be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/38010444/8966274

Comment: I'm okay with any option that only restricts me to using SVG, PNG, JPG and JPEG. Also, I want to alert the user in the html page by stating "Upload an image file"  when he/she uploads formats such as docx., .pdf etc. How do I create that error message and display it in my html page?

Comment: if you want to use FileField, and want to restrict the format allowed, you can use  **FileExtensionValidator** 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#fileextensionvalidator

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my Clordinary file upload, SVG is just an implementation detail):

```
class About(models.Model):
    icon = models.FileField(upload_to='about/', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```