# XML entities in Json.NET

Tags: .net, json.net

Json.NET support converting JSON to and from XML. So I tried simple code like this:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' standalone='no'?>
    <!DOCTYPE notes [
        <!ENTITY ent 'Sample text'>
    ]>
    <notes>
        <note>&ent;</note>
    </notes>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

As a result there is thrown exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:
Unexpected XmlNodeType when getting node name: EntityReference
```

I can't find any information about (non)supporting entities, so maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is explanatory: Json.NET apparently hasn't implemented conversion of [`XmlEntityReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlentityreference(v=vs.110).aspx) nodes to JSON.  This is the [`XmlNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx) subtype that is used to represent the `&ent;` [entity reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-entref).

To avoid the limitation you will need to expand entities while reading your XML, for instance like so:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    // Allow processing of DTD
    DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
    // On older versions of .Net instead set 
    //ProhibitDtd = false,
    // But for security, prevent DOS attacks by limiting the total number of characters that can be expanded to something sane.
    MaxCharactersFromEntities = (long)1e7,
    // And for security, disable resolution of entities from external documents.
    XmlResolver = null,
};
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
using (var textReader = new StringReader(xml))
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
{
    doc.Load(xmlReader);
}
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Notes:

- It's possible for an untrusted XML file to perform a Denial-of-Service attack by forcing an out-of-memory exception via cleverly crafted DTD entities and entity references, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3451203/3744182).  Setting [`XmlReaderSettings.MaxCharactersFromEntities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.maxcharactersfromentities(v=vs.110).aspx) to something reasonable should mitigate that.

  This specific value was taken from the [reference source for `XDocument.Load()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,5584).  Modify to fit your needs.
- Similarly setting [`XmlReaderSettings.XmlResolver = null`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.xmlresolver(v=vs.110).aspx) prevents untrusted XML from generating unexpected requests to external resources.

Or you could switch to the `XDocument` API in which entities are always expanded and security settings are more appropriate by default:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tAjiZ1) showing that the `&ent;` node gets expanded to its value `Sample text`:

```
{
  "?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@standalone": "no"
  },
  "!DOCTYPE": {
    "@name": "notes",
    "@internalSubset": "\n        <!ENTITY ent 'Sample text'>\n    "
  },
  "notes": {
    "note": "Sample text"
  }
}
```

Comment: Whoa, thank you for great fiddle! This solve my problem, but I am also wondering, whether it is possible to deserialize these JSONs to initial XML with entities?

Comment: You mean, with entities, or with entity **references**?  entity references are definitely not supported, logic for them simply doesn't appear in [`XmlNodeConverter.cs`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs).  If entities, I'm not sure.  Can you ask another question with a [mcve]?

Comment: @andrzej1_1 - XmlTextReader is deprecated so updated answer to use XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings)

Comment: I mean entity references, so there is no need to ask another question if you said they are not supported. And thanks for update.

Comment: @andrzej1_1 - you could request an enhancement to `XmlNodeConverter.cs` to support them at https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues.

Comment: It's not necessary for me, I was just curious if they are supported.