# Exception when deserializing an xml file containing a simple referenced entity

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xml-serialization

I am getting an exception

> XmlException: Unexpected node type EntityReference. ReadElementString method can only be called on elements with simple or empty content.

When using this simple bit of code:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(entry[]), new XmlRootAttribute("JMdict"));
    return (entry[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

I used xsd.exe to generate my c# classes from the xsd file. (note: truncated because of body length but I think the essential is there to solve the problem):

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //     This code was generated by a tool.
    //     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
    //
    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    //     the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    // 
    // This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.7.2046.0.
    // 


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.7.2046.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("JMdict", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class JMdict
    {

        private entry[] entryField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("entry")]
        public entry[] entry
        {
            get
            {
                return this.entryField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.entryField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.7.2046.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    public partial class entry
    {

        private string ent_seqField;

        private k_ele[] k_eleField;

        private r_ele[] r_eleField;

        private sense[] senseField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string ent_seq
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ent_seqField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ent_seqField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("k_ele")]
        public k_ele[] k_ele
        {
            get
            {
                return this.k_eleField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.k_eleField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("r_ele")]
        public r_ele[] r_ele
        {
            get
            {
                return this.r_eleField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.r_eleField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("sense")]
        public sense[] sense
        {
            get
            {
                return this.senseField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.senseField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.7.2046.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    public partial class k_ele
    {

        private string kebField;

        private string[] ke_infField;

        private string[] ke_priField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string keb
        {
            get
            {
                return this.kebField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.kebField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ke_inf")]
        public string[] ke_inf
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ke_infField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ke_infField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ke_pri")]
        public string[] ke_pri
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ke_priField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ke_priField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.7.2046.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    public partial class r_ele
    {

        private string rebField;

        private string re_nokanjiField;

        private string[] re_restrField;

        private string[] re_infField;

        private string[] re_priField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string reb
        {
            get
            {
                return this.rebField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.rebField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string re_nokanji
        {
            get
            {
                return this.re_nokanjiField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.re_nokanjiField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("re_restr")]
        public string[] re_restr
        {
            get
            {
                return this.re_restrField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.re_restrField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("re_inf")]
        public string[] re_inf
        {
            get
            {
                return this.re_infField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.re_infField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("re_pri")]
        public string[] re_pri
        {
            get
            {
                return this.re_priField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.re_priField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.7.2046.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    public partial class sense
    {

        private string[] stagkField;

        private string[] stagrField;

        private string[] posField;

        private string[] xrefField;

        private string[] antField;

        private string[] fieldField;

        private string[] miscField;

        private string[] s_infField;

        private lsource[] lsourceField;

        private string[] dialField;

        private gloss[] glossField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("stagk")]
        public string[] stagk
        {
            get
            {
                return this.stagkField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.stagkField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("stagr")]
        public string[] stagr
        {
            get
            {
                return this.stagrField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.stagrField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("pos")]
        public string[] pos
        {
            get
            {
                return this.posField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.posField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("xref")]
        public string[] xref
        {
            get
            {
                return this.xrefField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.xrefField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ant")]
        public string[] ant
        {
            get
            {
                return this.antField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.antField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("field")]
        public string[] field
        {
            get
            {
                return this.fieldField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.fieldField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("misc")]
        public string[] misc
        {
            get
            {
                return this.miscField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.miscField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("s_inf")]
        public string[] s_inf
        {
            get
            {
                return this.s_infField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.s_infField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("lsource")]
        public lsource[] lsource
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lsourceField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lsourceField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("dial")]
        public string[] dial
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dialField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dialField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("gloss")]
        public gloss[] gloss
        {
            get
            {
                return this.glossField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.glossField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the start of the xml file I am trying to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE JMdict [
  <!ELEMENT JMdict (entry*)>
  <!ELEMENT entry (ent_seq,k_ele*,r_ele+,sense+)>
  <!ELEMENT ent_seq (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT k_ele (keb,ke_inf*,ke_pri*)>
  <!ELEMENT keb (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT ke_inf (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT ke_pri (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT r_ele (reb,re_nokanji?,re_restr*,re_inf*,re_pri*)>
  <!ELEMENT reb (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT re_nokanji (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT re_restr (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT re_inf (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT re_pri (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT sense (stagk*,stagr*,pos*,xref*,ant*,field*,misc*,s_inf*,lsource*,dial*,gloss*)>
  <!ELEMENT stagk (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT stagr (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT xref (#PCDATA)*>
  <!ELEMENT ant (#PCDATA)*>
  <!ELEMENT pos (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT field (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT misc (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT lsource (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST lsource xml:lang CDATA "eng">
  <!ATTLIST lsource ls_type CDATA #IMPLIED>
  <!ATTLIST lsource ls_wasei CDATA #IMPLIED>
  <!ELEMENT dial (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT gloss (#PCDATA|pri)*>
  <!ATTLIST gloss xml:lang CDATA "eng">
  <!ATTLIST gloss g_gend CDATA #IMPLIED>
  <!ELEMENT pri (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT s_inf (#PCDATA)>
  <!ENTITY MA "martial arts term">
  <!ENTITY X "rude or X-rated term (not displayed in educational software)">
  <!ENTITY abbr "abbreviation">
  <!ENTITY adj-i "adjective (keiyoushi)">
  <!ENTITY adj-ix "adjective (keiyoushi) - yoi/ii class">
  <!ENTITY adj-na "adjectival nouns or quasi-adjectives (keiyodoshi)">
  <!ENTITY adj-no "nouns which may take the genitive case particle `no'">
  <!ENTITY adj-pn "pre-noun adjectival (rentaishi)">
  <!ENTITY adj-t "`taru' adjective">
  <!ENTITY adj-f "noun or verb acting prenominally">
  <!ENTITY adv "adverb (fukushi)">
  <!ENTITY adv-to "adverb taking the `to' particle">
  <!ENTITY arch "archaism">
  <!ENTITY ateji "ateji (phonetic) reading">
  <!ENTITY aux "auxiliary">
  <!ENTITY aux-v "auxiliary verb">
  <!ENTITY aux-adj "auxiliary adjective">
  <!ENTITY Buddh "Buddhist term">
  <!ENTITY chem "chemistry term">
  <!ENTITY chn "children's language">
  <!ENTITY col "colloquialism">
  <!ENTITY comp "computer terminology">
  <!ENTITY conj "conjunction">
  <!ENTITY cop-da "copula">
  <!ENTITY ctr "counter">
  <!ENTITY derog "derogatory">
  <!ENTITY eK "exclusively kanji">
  <!ENTITY ek "exclusively kana">
  <!ENTITY exp "expressions (phrases, clauses, etc.)">
  <!ENTITY fam "familiar language">
  <!ENTITY fem "female term or language">
  <!ENTITY food "food term">
  <!ENTITY geom "geometry term">
  <!ENTITY gikun "gikun (meaning as reading) or jukujikun (special kanji reading)">
  <!ENTITY hon "honorific or respectful (sonkeigo) language">
  <!ENTITY hum "humble (kenjougo) language">
  <!ENTITY iK "word containing irregular kanji usage">
  <!ENTITY id "idiomatic expression">
  <!ENTITY ik "word containing irregular kana usage">
  <!ENTITY int "interjection (kandoushi)">
  <!ENTITY io "irregular okurigana usage">
  <!ENTITY iv "irregular verb">
  <!ENTITY ling "linguistics terminology">
  <!ENTITY m-sl "manga slang">
  <!ENTITY male "male term or language">
  <!ENTITY male-sl "male slang">
  <!ENTITY math "mathematics">
  <!ENTITY mil "military">
  <!ENTITY n "noun (common) (futsuumeishi)">
  <!ENTITY n-adv "adverbial noun (fukushitekimeishi)">
  <!ENTITY n-suf "noun, used as a suffix">
  <!ENTITY n-pref "noun, used as a prefix">
  <!ENTITY n-t "noun (temporal) (jisoumeishi)">
  <!ENTITY num "numeric">
  <!ENTITY oK "word containing out-dated kanji">
  <!ENTITY obs "obsolete term">
  <!ENTITY obsc "obscure term">
  <!ENTITY ok "out-dated or obsolete kana usage">
  <!ENTITY oik "old or irregular kana form">
  <!ENTITY on-mim "onomatopoeic or mimetic word">
  <!ENTITY pn "pronoun">
  <!ENTITY poet "poetical term">
  <!ENTITY pol "polite (teineigo) language">
  <!ENTITY pref "prefix">
  <!ENTITY proverb "proverb">
  <!ENTITY prt "particle">
  <!ENTITY physics "physics terminology">
  <!ENTITY rare "rare">
  <!ENTITY sens "sensitive">
  <!ENTITY sl "slang">
  <!ENTITY suf "suffix">
  <!ENTITY uK "word usually written using kanji alone">
  <!ENTITY uk "word usually written using kana alone">
  <!ENTITY unc "unclassified">
  <!ENTITY yoji "yojijukugo">
  <!ENTITY v1 "Ichidan verb">
  <!ENTITY v1-s "Ichidan verb - kureru special class">
  <!ENTITY v2a-s "Nidan verb with 'u' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v4h "Yodan verb with `hu/fu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v4r "Yodan verb with `ru' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v5aru "Godan verb - -aru special class">
  <!ENTITY v5b "Godan verb with `bu' ending">
  <!ENTITY v5g "Godan verb with `gu' ending">
  <!ENTITY v5k "Godan verb with `ku' ending">
  <!ENTITY v5k-s "Godan verb - Iku/Yuku special class">
  <!ENTITY v5m "Godan verb with `mu' ending">
  <!ENTITY v5n "Godan verb with `nu' ending">
  <!ENTITY v5r "Godan verb with `ru' ending">
  <!ENTITY v5r-i "Godan verb with `ru' ending (irregular verb)">
  <!ENTITY v5s "Godan verb with `su' ending">
  <!ENTITY v5t "Godan verb with `tsu' ending">
  <!ENTITY v5u "Godan verb with `u' ending">
  <!ENTITY v5u-s "Godan verb with `u' ending (special class)">
  <!ENTITY v5uru "Godan verb - Uru old class verb (old form of Eru)">
  <!ENTITY vz "Ichidan verb - zuru verb (alternative form of -jiru verbs)">
  <!ENTITY vi "intransitive verb">
  <!ENTITY vk "Kuru verb - special class">
  <!ENTITY vn "irregular nu verb">
  <!ENTITY vr "irregular ru verb, plain form ends with -ri">
  <!ENTITY vs "noun or participle which takes the aux. verb suru">
  <!ENTITY vs-c "su verb - precursor to the modern suru">
  <!ENTITY vs-s "suru verb - special class">
  <!ENTITY vs-i "suru verb - irregular">
  <!ENTITY kyb "Kyoto-ben">
  <!ENTITY osb "Osaka-ben">
  <!ENTITY ksb "Kansai-ben">
  <!ENTITY ktb "Kantou-ben">
  <!ENTITY tsb "Tosa-ben">
  <!ENTITY thb "Touhoku-ben">
  <!ENTITY tsug "Tsugaru-ben">
  <!ENTITY kyu "Kyuushuu-ben">
  <!ENTITY rkb "Ryuukyuu-ben">
  <!ENTITY nab "Nagano-ben">
  <!ENTITY hob "Hokkaido-ben">
  <!ENTITY vt "transitive verb">
  <!ENTITY vulg "vulgar expression or word">
  <!ENTITY adj-kari "`kari' adjective (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY adj-ku "`ku' adjective (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY adj-shiku "`shiku' adjective (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY adj-nari "archaic/formal form of na-adjective">
  <!ENTITY n-pr "proper noun">
  <!ENTITY v-unspec "verb unspecified">
  <!ENTITY v4k "Yodan verb with `ku' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v4g "Yodan verb with `gu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v4s "Yodan verb with `su' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v4t "Yodan verb with `tsu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v4n "Yodan verb with `nu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v4b "Yodan verb with `bu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v4m "Yodan verb with `mu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2k-k "Nidan verb (upper class) with `ku' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2g-k "Nidan verb (upper class) with `gu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2t-k "Nidan verb (upper class) with `tsu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2d-k "Nidan verb (upper class) with `dzu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2h-k "Nidan verb (upper class) with `hu/fu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2b-k "Nidan verb (upper class) with `bu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2m-k "Nidan verb (upper class) with `mu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2y-k "Nidan verb (upper class) with `yu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2r-k "Nidan verb (upper class) with `ru' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2k-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `ku' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2g-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `gu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2s-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `su' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2z-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `zu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2t-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `tsu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2d-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `dzu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2n-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `nu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2h-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `hu/fu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2b-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `bu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2m-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `mu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2y-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `yu' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2r-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `ru' ending (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY v2w-s "Nidan verb (lower class) with `u' ending and `we' conjugation (archaic)">
  <!ENTITY archit "architecture term">
  <!ENTITY astron "astronomy, etc. term">
  <!ENTITY baseb "baseball term">
  <!ENTITY biol "biology term">
  <!ENTITY bot "botany term">
  <!ENTITY bus "business term">
  <!ENTITY econ "economics term">
  <!ENTITY engr "engineering term">
  <!ENTITY finc "finance term">
  <!ENTITY geol "geology, etc. term">
  <!ENTITY law "law, etc. term">
  <!ENTITY mahj "mahjong term">
  <!ENTITY med "medicine, etc. term">
  <!ENTITY music "music term">
  <!ENTITY Shinto "Shinto term">
  <!ENTITY shogi "shogi term">
  <!ENTITY sports "sports term">
  <!ENTITY sumo "sumo term">
  <!ENTITY zool "zoology term">
  <!ENTITY joc "jocular, humorous term">
  <!ENTITY anat "anatomical term">
]>
<JMdict>
   <entry>
      <ent_seq>1000000</ent_seq>
      <r_ele>
         <reb>ヽ</reb>
      </r_ele>
      <r_ele>
         <reb>くりかえし</reb>
      </r_ele>
      <sense>
         <pos>&n;</pos>
         <gloss xml:lang="eng">repetition mark in katakana</gloss>
      </sense>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <ent_seq>1000010</ent_seq>
      <r_ele>
         <reb>ヾ</reb>
      </r_ele>
      <r_ele>
         <reb>くりかえし</reb>
      </r_ele>
      <sense>
         <pos>&n;</pos>
         <gloss xml:lang="eng">voiced repetition mark in katakana</gloss>
      </sense>
   </entry>
</JMdict>
```

The error line corresponds to the `<pos>&n;</pos>` at the end so it's like he is not able to map the referenced entity (`<!ENTITY n "noun (common) (futsuumeishi)">`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell `XmlSerializer` (or rather, the underlying `XmlReader`) that it is safe to expand [XML entity references](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-entref)  by setting [`XmlReaderSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.dtdprocessing(v=vs.110).aspx) like so:

```
static entry[] DeserializeEntries(string filePath)
{
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        // Allow processing of DTD
        DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
        // On older versions of .Net instead set 
        //ProhibitDtd = false,
        // But for security, prevent DOS attacks by limiting the total number of characters that can be expanded to something sane.
        MaxCharactersFromEntities = (long)1e7,
        // And for security, disable resolution of entities from external documents.
        XmlResolver = null,
    };

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(entry[]), new XmlRootAttribute("JMdict"));
        return (entry[])serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- It's possible for an untrusted XML to perform a Denial-of-Service attack by forcing an out-of-memory exception via cleverly crafted DTD entities and entity references, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3451203/3744182).  Setting [`XmlReaderSettings.MaxCharactersFromEntities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.maxcharactersfromentities(v=vs.110).aspx) to something reasonable should mitigate that.

  This specific value was taken from the [reference source for `XElement.Load()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,3989).  Modify to fit your needs.
- Similarly setting [`XmlReaderSettings.XmlResolver = null`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.xmlresolver(v=vs.110).aspx) prevents an untrusted XML file from generating unexpected requests to external resources.
- If you are going to construct an `XmlSerializer` using an `XmlRootAttribute` override, you must statically cache the serializer to avoid a severe memory leak, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897411/3744182).

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9NDoI7).

Comment: Hi and thanks! It works but it's super slow...the original xml size is 45MB and it's taking ages to parse, would you happen to know why?

Comment: @ibiza - Can't say for certain but perhaps because the effective size of the XML document is much larger after all the entities are expanded?  Also your question is missing the `lsource` and `gloss` types so perhaps something is going on there.  Really I would need to see profile information to say for sure, but since the preferred format here is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/344280) you might want to ask a second question.

Comment: ok thanks, but I believe there is a way to avoid the XmlReader and only go with the XmlSerializer, do you have an idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Internally `XmlSerializer` always constructs an `XmlReader` to do basic parsing of the XML, see the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs,361) for examples.